# Uniform distribution with restricted domain in dimensions $\ge 2$

Tags: random

I want to generate numbers from a 2D "cylindrical" distribution, whose PDF would be:

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}1/(45^2 \pi) & x^2+y^2 \le 45\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

I don't know if it is still called a uniform distribution since it is in 2D with the domain restricted to $x^2+y^2 \le 45$, so it is not rectangular.

I wrote the function `dist[x_, y_] := If[Sqrt[(0 - x)^2 + (0 - y)^2] <= 45, 1./(Pi*45^2), 0]`

and I confirmed that `Integrate[dist[x, y], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 1.`

but I have no idea how to generate random $(x,y)$ couples from that point.

I'd like to use `RandomVariate` but it cannot be inputted with user-made PDFs.

Thanks !

Comment: Why not `RandomPoint@Disk[{0, 0}, 45]`?

Comment: Seems I don't have access to RandomPoint in Home Edition v.10.0.2.0

Answer (score 6):

You can take a random angle and a uniform random number between 0 and $45^2$ in the following manner:

```
n = 1000;
θ = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 2 π}], n];
r = (RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 45^2}], n]^0.5);

x = r  Cos[θ];
y = r  Sin[θ];

ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Uniform samples on a circle]

Comment: It works. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

One can always do rejection sampling:

```
With[{n = 1000, r = 45},
     k = 0;
     pts = Reap[While[cand = RandomReal[{-r, r}, 2]; 
                      If[cand.cand < r^2, Sow[cand]; k++]; k < n]][[-1, 1]]];
```

but if you are unwilling or unable to do this, use the results from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallPointPicking.html):

```
With[{n = 1000, r = 45},
     pts = Table[With[{v = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2], 
                       y = -Log[RandomReal[]]}, r v/Sqrt[v.v + y]], {n}];]
```

Both approaches easily extend to general $n$-dimensional ball sampling.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
ran = RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, Sqrt[45]], 10^3];
```

We can check the condition:

```
Max[(Norm /@ ran)^2] <= 45
```

which returns True.

Comment: The OP noted in the comments that his version does not yet have `RandomPoint[]`, but it is nevertheless good to have it here as an explicit answer.

Comment: @J.M. I apologize for not reading carefully. And I'm glad my answer is useful nevertheless.